# Debug problem with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am using a MonoTouch on Mac 10.6.6. When I run or debug the solution I get the following error:-

`Error merging Info.plist: invalid data.`

I am new to MonoTouch I have no idea of the reason. Please help me.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer [here](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2011-March/109969.html). Its a bug:

> --- Comment #1 from Geoff Norton 2011-03-10 14:26:27 UTC ---
>
> The current release of MonoDevelop does not support Xcode 4.  We will be
> issuing an update shortly to resolve this.